# Does this question remain the same when it is a subordinate clause: "Who can tell me what day is it today?"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, subordinate-clauses, adverbial-phrases

This is from an English teaching web site [School conversation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7isSwerYaQc) (see:01:15)

**Who can tell me what day is it today?**

As we know, a question sentence changes structure when it functions as a subordinate clause. E.g **"Tell me where you are going?" (not where are you going?")**

So, I would expect the same change of structure in the quetion **Who can tell me what day is it today?** However, it does not change and the subordinate part seems to have remained as is.

So I want to ask; should it not be put this way: **"Who can tell me what day IT IS today?**

Comment: Yes, it certainly should.

Comment: @KateBunting, Thanks Kate. In that case, I really wonder how can English teaching content be so bluntly wrong even with such simple things? Should we stop relying on them as teaching materials for students?

Comment: I've had a quick look at their website ('Kids' Pages'). The English is generally good but not perfect; it seems to have been written by a non-native speaker.

Comment: @Thanks again. I really appreciate your efforts and sincerity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should.

This is a common "mistake" in spoken English, caused (I suppose) by the speaker changing their mind half way through the sentence.

The standard embedded question, using a subordinate interrogative content clause would not include the inversion: "Tell me what time it is".  The main clause question would feature inversion "What time is it?".  The speaker has got their wires crossed and made a mistake.

Most native speaker would correct it in written text, if they notice it.